# Oracle 11G Multiple loop in through XML equals nodes in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

My XML looks like this.

```
 <mapaDatosUsuario>
           <item>
              <campo>pair1</campo>
              <valor>value1</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair2</campo>
              <valor>value2</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair3</campo>
              <valor>value3</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair4</campo>
              <valor>value4</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair5</campo>
              <valor>value5</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair6</campo>
              <valor>value6</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair7</campo>
              <valor>value7</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair8</campo>
              <valor>value8</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair9</campo>
              <valor>value9</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair10</campo>
              <valor>value10</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair11</campo>
              <valor>value11</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair12</campo>
              <valor>value12</valor>
           </item>
        </mapaDatosUsuario>
        <mapaDatosUsuario>
           <item>
              <campo>pair1</campo>
              <valor>value1</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair2</campo>
              <valor>value2</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair3</campo>
              <valor>value3</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair4</campo>
              <valor>value4</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair5</campo>
              <valor>value5</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair6</campo>
              <valor>value6</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair7</campo>
              <valor>value7</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair8</campo>
              <valor>value8</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair9</campo>
              <valor>value9</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair10</campo>
              <valor>value10</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair11</campo>
              <valor>value11</valor>
           </item>
           <item>
              <campo>pair12</campo>
              <valor>value12</valor>
           </item>
        </mapaDatosUsuario>
```

And i have a table where i have to storage some xml node with columns 
pair1
pair3
pair5
pair6
pair7

But i only extract mapaDatosUsuario but i dont know how i can extract the rest of the values

can i help me with that

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '//root/mapaDatosUsuario'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( '<root>' || your_xml || '</root>' )
         COLUMNS pair1 VARCHAR2(100) PATH './item/campo[text()="pair1"]/../valor/text()',
                 pair3 VARCHAR2(100) PATH './item/campo[text()="pair3"]/../valor/text()',
                 pair5 VARCHAR2(100) PATH './item/campo[text()="pair5"]/../valor/text()',
                 pair7 VARCHAR2(100) PATH './item/campo[text()="pair7"]/../valor/text()'
       );
```

**Output**:

```
PAIR1      PAIR3      PAIR5      PAIR7    
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
value1     value3     value5     value7    
value1     value3     value5     value7
```

Or, to get the XML nodes:

```
SELECT *
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '//root/mapaDatosUsuario'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( '<root>' || your_xml || '</root>' )
         COLUMNS pair1 XMLTYPE PATH './item/campo[text()="pair1"]/..',
                 pair3 XMLTYPE PATH './item/campo[text()="pair3"]/..',
                 pair5 XMLTYPE PATH './item/campo[text()="pair5"]/..',
                 pair7 XMLTYPE PATH './item/campo[text()="pair7"]/..'
       );
```

Comment: Wow great! Thanks a lot I tested the fisrt block and works perfectly!!